# How do I send a notification on specific time

Tags: android

I'm trying to send a reminder notification on specific time, but `BroadcastReciever` seems to work in a wrong way, also `JobIntentService` doesn't work at all.

Here is my custom `BroadcastReciever` code:

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, JobIntentService.class);
        context.startService(intent1);

        Log.d("KOK", "Receiver " + new Date().toString());

    }

}
```

JobIntentService:

```
public class JobIntentService extends androidx.core.app.JobIntentService {

    @Override
    protected void onHandleWork(@NonNull Intent intent) {

        NotificationHelper.sendTestNotification(this);

        Log.d("KOK", "JobIntentService");

        stopSelf();

    }
    
}
```

MainActivity.onCreate():

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        if (!prefs.getBoolean("firstTime", false)) {

            Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, Receiver.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent
                    .getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 17);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 48);
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                    60000L, pendingIntent);

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("firstTime", true);
            editor.apply();

            Log.d("KOK", "First time");

        }

        Log.d("KOK", "Main activity " + new Date().toString());
```

Here is log output:

```
2021-09-28 17:46:39.383 2822-2822/com.ivanuil.plantcare D/KOK: First time
2021-09-28 17:46:39.389 2822-2822/com.ivanuil.plantcare D/KOK: Main activity Tue Sep 28 17:46:39 GMT+03:00 2021
2021-09-28 17:48:15.141 2822-2822/com.ivanuil.plantcare D/KOK: Receiver Tue Sep 28 17:48:15 GMT+03:00 2021
2021-09-28 17:49:28.133 2822-2822/com.ivanuil.plantcare D/KOK: Receiver Tue Sep 28 17:49:28 GMT+03:00 2021
```

As you can see Receiver doesn't launch at a specified time and JobIntentService won't start at all

Please, help me solve this problem

Comment: You're setting the alarm for 17:48:00 of the same day.  Its firing at 17:48:15 of the same day.  That's as close as you're going to get with Android, this isn't a hard realtime system and it explicitly delays alarms for batching and other purposes. What are you doing with this that you need it to be within less than 15s of the time given, you may need to do things another way entirely.

Comment: @GabeSechan Thanks a lot! But I still don't get why JobIntentServise won't start

Comment: Well, the code posted never creates a job.  You need to do that.  I'm assuming it just wasn't in this version of the code, but I'd need to see it to help.  (Also jobs will have the same timing inaccuracy as the alarms, as jobs are built on top of them).

Comment: Simple fix: Use a normal `Service` class instead of a `JobIntentService` it should work.

Comment: the receiver doesn't launch at the specified time because of battery optimization on Android devices whose API level is >= KitKat (4.4)